# how do i use 'distinct' properly for my product query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a product catalog with
 a product table `(tblProducts : ProductID)`,
 a product category table `(tblProductCategories : CatID)`,
 a product sub-category table `(tblProductSubCategories : SubCatID)`, and
 a xref table `(tblProdXCat : ProductID,CatID,SubCatID)`
that links the products to cats and subcats.
Products can be linked to multiple cats and/or subcats.
How can I query and get distinct products only (no product duplicated in result set)?
Microsoft SQL Server please.

Thanks!

Comment: What columns do you want returned?

Comment: What constitutes a distinct product? Is Product A, Category A, Subcategory A DISTINCT from Product A, Category A, Subcategory B in your definition, or do you only want "Product A, Product B" ect. If the latter, do you want Category and Subcategory returned, and if so, does it matter which Category/Subcategory is returned with a product?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `tblProducts` table is a table of distinct products, so you aren't asking how to select distinct products from thence.

If you mean how to get distinct products from `tblProdXCat`, then it's probably as simple as `SELECT DISTINCT ProductID FROM tblProdXCat`.

But maybe you want a complete information about the products rather than simply their IDs. In that case you could just INNER JOIN that list of distinct `ProductID` values against `tblProducts`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ProductID FROM tblProdXCat) x
    ON p.ProductID = x.ProductID
```

If that is still not what you want then you may need to clarify your request.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct productID from tblProducts
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all the joining ambiguity into the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID in
(
  SELECT ProductId
  FROM Products JOIN ...
)
```